# How to construct a side-by-side boxplot for a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

Men and women are in a column labeled 'sex'. I want to plot them according to their happiness levels. 
So, one figure two columns and one row.

I have tried to extract each gender:

```py
men = df[df['sex'] == 'Men']
women = df[df['sex'] == 'Women']
df_happy_sex = df[['happy', 'sex']].copy()
```

![https://ibb.co/yqmWKkf]

Comment: link doesn't work. also, please provide some sample data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

I've created a imaginary sample of your data-frame.

```py
data = [['men', 55], ['men', 77], ['women', 85],
        ['men', 70], ['women', 68], ['women', 64],
        ['men', 86], ['men', 64], ['women', 54],
        ['men', 43], ['women', 86],  ['women', 91]]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['sex', 'happy'])
```

You can just:

```py
df.boxplot(by=['sex'], sym ='', figsize = [6, 6])
```

It yields:
I guess that is what you want.

[image: Hapiness]

Answer (score 2):

- [Boxplots in python](https://cduvallet.github.io/posts/2018/03/boxplots-in-python)
- Boxplots require a numeric component, as they are a visualization of statical data, specifically spread.
- Use [seaborn](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.boxplot.html) to make your plots look nicer

### Code:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt  # doesn't have color by hue
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np  # for generating random data
import random  # for random gender selection

np.random.seed(10)
random.seed(10)
df = pd.DataFrame({'age': [x for x in np.random.randint(20, 70, 100)],
                   'feeling': [random.choice(['happy', 'sad']) for _ in range(100)], 
                   'gender': [random.choice(['male', 'female']) for _ in range(100)]})

# display(df)
   age feeling  gender
0   29     sad  female
1   56     sad    male
2   35     sad  female
3   20     sad  female
4   69   happy  female

sns.boxplot(y='age', x='feeling', data=df, hue='gender')
plt.show()
```

[image]

### Using `groupby` with only categorical data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'feeling': [random.choice(['happy', 'sad|']) for _ in range(100)],
                   'gender': [random.choice(['male', 'female']) for _ in range(100)]})

df.groupby(['feeling','gender'])['gender'].count().plot(kind='bar')
```

[image]

### Alternate data - `feeling` as a numeric value:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'feeling': [x for x in np.random.randint(0, 101, 100)],
                   'gender': [random.choice(['male', 'female']) for _ in range(100)]})

plt.figure(figsize=(8, 7))
sns.boxplot(y='feeling', x='gender', data=df)
plt.show()
```

[image]